# 3 month free PS Plus membership

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I bought a 1 year PS Plus membership a month ago and I got a message regarding 3 extra months. Now I looked it up and it was a "Favor" from Sony as there's gonna be a price increase in PS Plus memberships. 
Now, when I check the expiration date for my PS Plus the date is still exactly 1 year. I wanna know if it automatically renews it to 3 more months or if my 3 free months haven't been counted. Do you guys know anyone who had something like this happen with them?

Comment: what was the message? can you quote or screenshot it? to me it sounds like an offer for buying the subscription and getting extra months for free (which was the case when i first got it)

Answer (score -3):

I think you missed the boat. There was a promo code you had to enter but they aren't offering it anymore. We bought a PS4 for Christmas 2017 and never saw the code offered.